# Continue iterating/repeating while loop until enter (or arbitrary key) is pressed

Tags: c, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to get a while loop to iterate until a key, ideally enter, is pressed.

Specifically, what I want is for a value to continually update and be visible to the user until he presses enter.

Here is the basic code I'm working with, which doesn't work as I'd like it to

```
while(1){       
    printf("Press Enter to Continue\n");    
    printf("Value to Update: %f\n",value_to_update); 
    usleep(10000);      
    system("clear"); 
    while(getchar() != '\n'){
        continue; 
    }       
};
```

Thanks. Happy to clarify anything I've said or answer other questions.

I'm not sure how to explain exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try two ways:

1) I want it to do what the following code does, except stop when the user presses enter:

```
while(1){           
    printf("Value to Update: %f\n",value_to_update); 
    usleep(10000);      
    system("clear"); 
};
```

2) I'll enumerate the steps

1) Print the value to update to the screen

2) Wait for N microseconds

3) Did the User Press enter?

3.False) If No: Clear the screen, Go to step 1

3.True) If Yes: Break from loop

I guess this is way way harder than I thought it would be.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by "doesn't work as I'd like it to"?  What is the output that you are seeing?

Comment: Post input used and output seen, output desired.

Comment: If you want this to operate in the background while you update the display in the foreground, you need to user OS-specific code, it can't be done in standard C.

Comment: _Side note:_ I'd move your `printf` calls to _after_ the screen clear. Otherwise, they'll be output and then the screen is cleared so fast, that the user probably won't see them and will be left with a blank screen, wondering what to do.

Comment: @Barmar Should be working on Linux?

Comment: Are you on WinX or POSIX (e.g. linux, BSD, macOS)? On POSIX, `getchar` will freeze, waiting for input. You'll need to issue an `ioctl` call to the TTY layer to put the input into raw mode, so you can poll it. Or, you'll need to do a `select` call on the `stdin` file descriptor (i.e. `STDIN_FILENO`) to poll for a ready char and then do `read` (vs. `getchar`). You could also use `fcntl` to put `STDIN_FILENO` (using `O_NONBLOCK`) to put the input into a non-blocking mode, so you can do the `read` directly.

Comment: `getchar()` is not your friend here, because it will block until it can return a character.  Moreover, the terminal will normally send data to your program a line at time, so if the user types any keys other than <Enter> then you'll have to go through multiple iterations of your loop before you get to the newline.  For something like this on Linux, you probably want to use I/O routines from [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or a similar library.

Comment: Would you guys consider posting some code? I'm not an expert at C.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that getchar() "blocks".  Consider using [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).  It's made-to-order for text-mode "screen control". Like waiting for the user to hit <Enter> ... or any other key, such as a control key.  It's callable from C, and it's platform-agnostic, including Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code that works using the `select` call.

It *only* works for newline because the kernel TTY layer will hold up until *it* gets a newline.

So, for any other char (e.g. space), we'd have to issue the `ioctl` calls I mentioned in my top comments to put the layer into "raw" mode (vs. the default of "cooked"). If you need that, see `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char buf[10];
    int len;
    fd_set rdset;

    fd = 0;

    while (1) {
        // this is do whatever until newline is pressed ...
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);

        // set up the select mask -- the list of file descriptors we want to
        // wait on for read/input data available
        FD_ZERO(&rdset);
        FD_SET(fd,&rdset);

        // set timeout of 1ms
        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 1000;

        // wait for action on stdin [or loop if timeout]
        // the first arg must be: the highest fd number in the mask + 1
        len = select(fd + 1,&rdset,NULL,NULL,&tv);
        if (len <= 0)
            continue;

        // we're guaranteed at least one char of input here
        len = read(fd,buf,1);
        if (len <= 0)
            continue;

        // wait for newline -- stop program when we get it
        if (buf[0] == '\n')
            break;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I really appreciate this. I don't think in a million years I would have figured this out for myself.

I know it's probably asking a lot, but would you mind commenting your code? I'd like to understand better what this is doing. 

Thank you anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. I've had to fiddle with this stuff for production code, so I was somewhat already familiar with it.

Comment: @GeneralPancake: before you wade neck deep into ioctl(), select() and friends - please consider trying [ncurses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/getting-started-ncurses), first.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(getchar() != '\n'){
        continue;
```

It does no do what you think.

You want to break first loop.

```
If(getchar() == char_which_breaks_the_loop) break;
```